# SQL Counting Rows based on break values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Frequently I need to do something in SQL Server that I just don't know how to do properly.

Basically, if I have a table `#sample` that is like this:

| DEPARTMENT | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| ACCOUNTING | A |
| FINANCE | A |
| PAYROLL | A |
| ACCOUNTING | B |
| PAYROLL | A |
| FINANCE | A |
| PAYROLL | B |
| PAYROLL | C |

I need to query that table to get an output that is this:

| DEPARTMENT | DATE | DUPECHECK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ACCOUNTING | A | 1 |
| ACCOUNTING | B | 2 |
| FINANCE | A | 1 |
| FINANCE | A | 1 |
| PAYROLL | A | 1 |
| PAYROLL | A | 1 |
| PAYROLL | B | 2 |
| PAYROLL | C | 3 |

In Oracle Hyperion Brio at my old job I used to create a column that value 1 for every row and writing a function Cume on that column with a break value of the column I needed to count.

In Excel, I could create a concatenated column that has my break values, and then do a `countif(concat:concat,concat1)` copy that formula down.

I feel like it should be something similar to this, but that's not it at all:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY #sample.Department ORDER BY #sample.Date) DUPECHECK
```

Help me out?

Comment: Replace row_niumber() with dense_rank()?

Comment: I guess now would be a good time to read the [documentation about ranking functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to learn about the others that are available.

Comment: @SMor Thank you.  That's very helpful.  Could've been a bit nicer (hit my ears like RTFM which I kinda deserve), but it was still very helpful.  I've included that in my edit of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, ROW_NUMBER() is part of the set of [ranking functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

For your purposes, you can use the [DENSE_RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql):

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY #sample.Department ORDER BY #sample.Date)DUPECHECK
```